# App Sandbox issue on OSX 10.8

Tags: macos, xcode5, appstore-sandbox

I'm using the following App Sandbox Temporary Exception Entitlements in my Mac app.

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events  com.apple.iTunes

com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write  /Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/
```

If I build my app in OS X 10.9.4 with enabling App Sandbox, and run it in OS X 10.8.5, my app reports App Sandbox is enabled in activity monitor.  But get an error which I coded.

If I build my app in OS X 10.8.5 with enabling App Sandbox, and run it in OS X 10.8.5, my app reports App Sandbox is not enabled in activity monitor.  Then my app runs without any error.

I can't understand why this kind of phenomenon occur.  I don't touch any code in 10.9.4 and 10.8.5.  Please help me!

Do I need provide two version which is App Sandbox enabled one and not enabled App Sandbox for my app?

Also, Apple rejects "temporary-exception" used app.  Is that true?
I'm not joind with Apple Developer Program, but if my app have possibility to delivered in Mac App Store,  I will join with Apple Developer Program.

Comment: You should contact Apple for the answer to both of these questions, which you can do after joining the Apple Developer Program. It may be you will have to make the app require OS X 10.9 and newer. You may also have to use some method other than the temporary exemption to get out of the sandbox. There are other options, depending on what your app does.

Comment: My app must get information from iTunes and must write information to iTunes. So those exception can't be removed.  Do you mean that kind of app could not be distributed via Mac App Store?

Comment: I have chicken and egg problem.  If my app is a kind of app which Apple reject, I don't have any reason to join Apple Developer Program.  But Apple does not provide a place to question about App Sandboxing for non Apple Developer Program.  Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: For the app store approval, you can contact Apple and ask today. But their policies are constantly changing and might be different tomorrow. They will not make any promises to a small developer they've never heard of about about what their policies will be in the future. If you were Microsoft or Adobe, then they might make promises about the future. Maybe.

Comment: I'm not, however, convinced that you need these temporary exemptions. You can access iTunes without the temporary home directory read/write exemption. Apps are allowed to write to any location so long as it's owned by the logged in user and the user has specifically instructed the app to access that part of the disk. Also, iTunes is not always stored in the home directory so the "home-relative-path" exemption doesn't even help you. It's often on a completely different HDD.

Comment: The correct way to find out if you need an exemption is to file a Technical Support Incident with Apple. But you can't file one of these unless you are a paying member.

Comment: Yes, there is a chicken and egg problem here. But Apple doesn't really care about that. You do care... and you're going to have to pay the $99.

Comment: As for your issue with 10.8 vs 10.9, again you should file a TSI about that. It's not the sort of problem people on stack overflow can help you with — since it's too specific to your code base. Apple will help you however. But only if you're a paying member.

Comment: I found out `com.apple.security.scripting-targets`, `com.apple.iTunes.library.read-write` and `com.apple.iTunes.appleevent-send`. But `appleevent-send` seems to requires code signature, i.e. paid member.  So if I really want to my app to sandboxed, It seems that I should be a paid member.  Also, I think strange behavior in 10.8 should be tested with new entitlement.  Thank you for your support!!